# Local method not getting executed in Statefulwidget class in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class where I want to display a list of documents from a Firestore database. I have created a method, _getTrxnData, to get the documents but it never gets executed.

How do I get this method to be executed when the page loads?

I don't know what the execution process is for something like this.

```
class CompanyDashboardScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_dashboard_screen';

  const CompanyDashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CompanyDashboardScreen> createState() =>
      _CompanyDashboardScreenState();
}

class _CompanyDashboardScreenState
    extends ConsumerState<CompanyDashboardScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;

  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemsTrxn;
  bool isLoaded = false;

  _getTrxnData() async {
    var collectionTrxn = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('company')
        .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
        .collection('trxns');

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> tempList = [];
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var dataTrxn = await collectionTrxn.get();

    dataTrxn.docs.forEach((element) {
      tempList.add(element.data());
    });

    setState(() {
      itemsTrxn = tempList;
      isLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: CustomAppBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: const Text("User Profile"),
                onTap: () {
                  MainScreen.of(context)
                      ?.setIndex(3); // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen()));
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: isLoaded
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: itemsTrxn.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      _getTrxnData(); <<<< METHOD HERE

                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: ListTile(
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          title: Row(
                            children: [
       
                       Text(
                                'Client: ${itemsTrxn[index]['clientFName'] ?? 'n/a'} ${itemsTrxn[index]['clientLName'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  '${itemsTrxn[index]['propertyAddress'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                  '${itemsTrxn[index]['propertyCity'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                  '${itemsTrxn[index]['propertyState'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '\nPrice: ${itemsTrxn[index]['contractPrice'] == null ? 'n/a' : NumberFormat.simpleCurrency().format(itemsTrxn[index]['contractPrice'])}\nStatus: ${itemsTrxn[index]['trxnStatus'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                              'MLS#: ${itemsTrxn[index]['mlsNumber'] ?? 'n/a'}\n${itemsTrxn[index]['clientType']}'),
                          onTap: () {
                            //MainScreen.of(context)?.setIndex(2);  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
                            ref
                                .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                .updatenewTrxn(false);
                            ref
                                .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                .updatecurrentTrxnId(
                                    itemsTrxn[index]['trxnId']);
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => TransactionDetailScreen(
                                    itemsTrxn[index]['trxnId'])));
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : const Text('No Date')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget to execute that method.